# Different parse priorities when argument is Hash

Tags: ruby

Two cases:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > puts {}.class

 => NilClass
```

and

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 > puts "a".class
String
 => nil
```

It looks like `puts {}.class` is equivalent to `(puts {}).class` and `puts "a".class` is equivalent to `puts ("a".class)`. Why is it so?

Comment: My guess: It's treating `{}` as a block, not as a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's treating `{}` as a block, not as a hash. RubyInside says so, and also shows how you can [prove it using Ripper](http://www.rubyinside.com/using-ripper-to-see-how-ruby-is-parsing-your-code-5270.html).